# Google clould endpoint Api method generated without the required parameter

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I want to deploy v2 of my google endpoint API. in this version 2, i have added an ApiMethod with a parameter

```
 /**
 * An endpoint class we are exposing
 */
@Api(
  name = "myApi",
  version = "v2",
  namespace = @ApiNamespace(
    ownerDomain = "awesome.me.com",
    ownerName = "awesome.me.com",
    packagePath = "api/v2"
  )
)
public class MyEndpointV2 extends MyEndpoint{


  @ApiMethod(name = "getContact")
  public Charges getContact(ContactRequest request){
    return ContactHandler.getContact(request);
  }
}
```

As you can see, my V2 extends my V1 Api so i can access all my V1 methods. the issue is that,**my new method is generated without parameter** `ContactRequest`. that is when i try to call the method in my app module, it appears as follows

```
myapi.getContact()
```

What could be the problem?
I have tried to clean build my project but nothing happens

**EDIT**
Here's MyEndPoint class

```
 @Api(
      name = "myApi",
      version = "v1",
      namespace = @ApiNamespace(
        ownerDomain = "awesome.me.com",
        ownerName = "awesome.me.com",
        packagePath = ""
      )
    )
    public class MyEndpoint{


     @ApiMethod(name = "getPeriod")
  public Period getPeriod(@Named("days")long days) {
    return Handler.getPeriod(days);
  }
  //other api methods
    }
```

Comment: can you please post class MyEndpoint too?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer i have done so

Comment: @MichaelMeyer when i change my api method name from `getContact()` to something like `contact()` i can be able to pass the parameter `ContactRequest`. why that?

Comment: hmm, sounds strange. Which version of the SDK are you using? Maybe you should try a different version

Comment: @MichaelMeyer am using `com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.34` another thing when i have a boolean field in a class in endpoint. e.g `boolean valid = false`. the getter method in endpoint is generated as `public boolean isValid(){return valid;}` but in client library, i get a getter of type `Boolean` `Boolean getValid()`

Comment: I am using 1.9.48 for my project

Comment: @MichaelMeyer is it behaving like mine?

Comment: Can you post your discovery document? If you run a dev server it will be `http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/myApi/v1/rest`

Comment: @saiyr am not running on a development server. how can i get it from google app engine?

Comment: Just fill in your hostname instead of `localhost:8080`.

Answer (score 0):

This error may caused by your inheritance. Please read the following documentation

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/multiclass

It says that you have to use the same values for your annotations. You tried to override the values for Version and package. This can lead to undefined behaviour

Comment: didn't work. I had to rename my Api methods. e.g renamed `getContact(ContactRequest req){}` to `fetchContact(ContactRequest req){}`

Comment: what did you excactly? Did you remove the Annotations from your MyEndpointsV2 class? You do not need the Annotations in your inherited class

Comment: but i need to increment the version in my `MyEndpointsV2` class. that means i also have to include annotations in my `MyEndpointsV2` class